# Jenkins order of triggering other jobs in post build actions

Tags: jenkins

I have a freestyle job and in the Post Build Actions section I have configured Build Other Projects and set three other jobs(e.g. j1,j2,j3) to be built as other projects.

I want to ask, will other projects will always be triggered in the specified order. Like j1 will be triggered first, then j2 and then j3. Or order of trigger is not guaranteed.

Comment: Yes in same order they will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure they run in a certain order you have to add a postbuild trigger to each job.
In your case they can also run parallel, if you allow enough threads.

It sound like a jenkins pipline would be a good idea:

https://jenkins.io/solutions/pipeline/